# Adjusting margins on .CSS

Tags: css, pdf, margin, margins

I am using a program to convert a logbook into a PDF, however every time the PDF document is generated the left margin is greater.  Does this have something to do with the .css file?  Below is a copy of what is in that file:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*

Report Type: onePage
Report Category: China
Rows Per Page: 14
Data Type: Flight

*/

@media print 
{
    .content_left
    {
        height:1in;
    }
}


tbody td,th
{
    font-size:6.5pt;
}

thead td
{
    font-size:6.5pt;
}

.p1us
{
    color:grey;
}
.twoCell_top
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

thead th.secondaryColumnHeading{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:6pt;
}
thead th.tertiaryColumnHeading
{
    font-size:6pt;
}

#date
{
    height:.25in;
    width:.5in;
}

#journey {width:1in;}

.borderTopOnly
{
    border:solid 1px white;
}

th.grandTotal
{
    border-width: 0px;
    /*text-align: right;*/
}

th.pageTotals
{
    border-width: 0px;
    /*text-align: right;*/
}

.text
{
    width:1in;
    white-space:normal;
    height:.35in;
}

.text_small
{
    width:.7in;
}

.text_medium
{
    width:.6in;
    white-space:normal;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code, not just css file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ashkan.  Okay, I have no coding skills or anything like that.  I'm just trying to solve a printing issue I have, so please bear with me if I sound like an absolute clown.  The whole package for my report includes the css file and a few HTML files.